# Excel Web App <-> ODBC database with read/write

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office-web-components

Is it possible to create a Excel Web App (hosting in SharePoint) with connections to a ODBC database (e.g. PostGreSQL, SQL Server, or Oracle)

WHERE

The Query to the Database (read) includes the Employee Name (which is coming from a field in the spreadsheet, and uses that to populate the Excel Worksheet (currently we use a VLOOKUP to pull this data from a different EXCEL sheet, But that does not work with web parts).

And then we would like to be able to write back the data that the  user fills into the Excel Web part to tables in the database.

That would also mean parameter-izing the SQL query so that it writes to the correct table?

---

If all of this is not possible, what do people think of a Scraper program that would read all 500+ employee excel workbooks (stored in SharePoint as Web App) where each employee puts there future time needs into the sheet, and then the Scraper will read through all the workbooks and populate the DB?